# Configure IIS with DSC

Tags: powershell, iis, configuration, dsc

How one would configure static\dynamic http compression using xWebAdministration DSC module? As far as I understand DSC doesn't offer a direct way to configure those, but maybe xWebConfigKeyValue can do that? If so, have you got some examples?

And also this:

```
New-WebHandler -Name "svc-ISAPI-4.0_64bit" -Path "*.svc" -Verb 'GET,POST' -Modules IsapiModule
New-WebHandler -Name "svc-Integrated-4.0" -Path "*.svc" -Verb 'GET,POST' -Modules 'System.ServiceModel.Activation.ServiceHttpHandlerFactory, System.ServiceModel.Activation, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'
```

With xIisHandler? but how?

Solution:

```
$mimeTypesDynamic = @(
    @{mimeType='text/*'; enabled='True'},
    @{mimeType='message/*'; enabled='True'},
    @{mimeType='application/x-javascript'; enabled='True'},
    @{mimeType='application/json'; enabled='True'},
    @{mimeType='application/json; charset=utf-8'; enabled='True'},
    @{mimeType='application/xml" enabled'; enabled='True'},
    @{mimeType='application/xml; charset=utf-8'; enabled='True'},
    @{mimeType='*/*'; enabled='false'}
)

$mimeTypesStatic = @(
    @{mimeType='text/*'; enabled='True'},
    @{mimeType='message/*'; enabled='True'},
    @{mimeType='application/x-javascript'; enabled='True'},
    @{mimeType='application/atom+xml'; enabled='True'},
    @{mimeType='application/xaml+xml'; enabled='True'},
    @{mimeType='*/*'; enabled='false'}
)

...


Script configureMime {
    SetScript = {
        Remove-WebHandler -Name "svc-Integrated-4.0" -WarningAction SilentlyContinue
        Remove-WebHandler -Name "svc-ISAPI-4.0_64bit"
        Clear-WebConfiguration -filter "/system.webServer/httpCompression/dynamicTypes" -pspath IIS: -WarningAction SilentlyContinue
        Clear-WebConfiguration -filter "/system.webServer/httpCompression/staticTypes" -pspath IIS: -WarningAction SilentlyContinue
        foreach ($mimeD in $using:mimeTypesDynamic) {
            Add-WebConfiguration "/system.webServer/httpCompression/dynamicTypes" -pspath IIS: -value $mimeD
            New-Item c:\1 -ItemType Directory -ea 0
        }
        foreach ($mimeS in $using:mimeTypesStatic) {
            Add-WebConfiguration "/system.webServer/httpCompression/staticTypes" -pspath IIS: -value $mimeS
        }
        New-WebHandler -Name "svc-ISAPI-4.0_64bit" -Path "*.svc" -Verb 'GET,POST' -Modules IsapiModule
        New-WebHandler -Name "svc-Integrated-4.0" -Path "*.svc" -Verb 'GET,POST' -Modules 'System.ServiceModel.Activation.ServiceHttpHandlerFactory, System.ServiceModel.Activation, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'
    }
    TestScript = { 
        $types = Get-WebConfigurationProperty -Filter "/system.webServer/httpCompression" -name dynamicTypes
        $types.Collection.Length -eq 8
    }
    GetScript = { return @{ 'Result' = "Mimi Configuration" } }   
}
```

Comment: xIISHandler only accepts a predefined list of handlers (https://github.com/PowerShell/xWebAdministration/blob/dev/DSCResources/MSFT_xIIsHandler/MSFT_xIisHandler.psm1).  You can use a script-resource.

Comment: ok, and do you know about the compression? @FrodeF.

Comment: You'll probably need xwebconfigkeyvalue (or use script resource). Search for PowerShell examples to find the paths and values you need to set it

Comment: well, that's exactly what I'm asking for, I was unable to find anything relevant on this topic...and I don't know IIS all that good to understand what is actually happening @FrodeF.

Comment: also, xWebConfigKeyValue states that it needs path to website, what if I want these settings to be glonal? @FrodeF.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I can see from the source code for [xWebAdministration](https://github.com/PowerShell/xWebAdministration) it looks like xWebConfigKeyValue only supports appsettings-values and xIISHandler only accepts predefined handlers. So you would have to use script-resource or create your own resources to configure these settings (or find some third-party modules).

To get you started, here are samples to modify dynamic and static compression on the global level:

```
#Enable dynamicCompression global (remember to install dynamic compression feature first)
Set-WebConfigurationProperty -Filter "/system.webServer/urlCompression" -PSPath IIS:\ -Name doDynamicCompression -Value "true"

#Enable staticCompression global
Set-WebConfigurationProperty -Filter "/system.webServer/urlCompression" -PSPath IIS:\ -Name doStaticCompression -Value "true"
```

Comment: I assume this is something else? I mean, urlCompression != httpCompression? I was looking to do this: `appcmd.exe set config -section:system.webServer/httpCompression /+"staticTypes.[mimeType='text/*',enabled='True']" /commit:apphost`. And obviously I cannot just set it to true, need to pass in actual data `mimiType='text/*' (and perhaps `enabled='True'` also?). Also, I suppose I can test existence with `Get-WebConfigurationProperty`?

Comment: You never specified what you were looking to configure.... This is how you enable/disable http compression. The httpcompression-section is used to define how it behaves once enabled. FYI, I've voted to close this question as it's unclear. Please read the help on StackOverflow and update the question.

Comment: well, thanks for telling, but as you probably figured, I have 7k rating here and I'm pretty good with rules, but its the best I can ask this question because I've never worked with IIS.